# Creating an endless recurring task in rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a long running task that I want to loop forever in TypeScript.

It should only run the next task when the previous task has completed.

I want to use rxjs for this as it seems the most succinct way to do it.

So far I've used a combination of interval, queue scheduler, defer, exhaust and exhaust map but not had much luck.

This is what I have so far:

```
function longTask () : void {
    // some long running task
}

interval(1000)
.pipe(
     exhaustMap((x) => 
         defer(()=> longTask())
     )
.subscribe();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should refer this, I think it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021728/add-queueing-to-angulars-httpclient

Comment: It also should only run the next task when the previous task has not yet completed? means all task queued should run at the same time ?

Comment: @fan cheung - Yeah you're right I've updated it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740884/queuing-function-using-rxjs/56745598#56745598  - I answered in other post, very simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Use zip, zip will fire the interval and then wait for your observable to fire.

```
zip(interval(1000), longTask()).subscribe(([_, longTaskResult]) => {
});
```

Or if your longTask only emits once and completes you could make a recursive call

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { delay } = rxjs.operators;

const longTask = () => of(Math.random() * 10).pipe(delay(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)));

const runLongTask = () => {
  longTask().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    runLongTask();
  });
}

runLongTask();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```